# Get specific value inside a string javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this values:

- 4Green (Blister) [Others]
- !@#$%^&*()'RWEW<>?P{}:" [Sachet]
- TRIAL [Sachet]

How do I get the value inside [] only I don't need any other value. Just the string inside the [] part like Sachet or Others in javascript. I need them and Pass it to my ajax function

Comment: Use RegEx to fetch anything between []. Check the options for it being not-greedy (if it's what you're looking for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regular expression is the fastest way here; you can use this one: `(\[\w+\])+` or `(\[.*\])` or `\[(.*?)]`.

**UPDATE**

```
var samples = [ '4Green (Blister) [Others]', '!@#$%^&*()\'RWEW<>?P{}:" [Sachet]',
    'TRIAL [Sachet]'];
var regex = /\[(.*?)]/;

for (var i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
  console.log(samples[i].match(regex)[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
machina@6PXM10I> node regex.js
Others
Sachet
Sachet
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a regular expression for whatever reason, you can do it this way:

1. You could obtain each string you want to test, perhaps with document.getElementsByClassName, and then cycle through the array-like Collection it returns to extract each string.
2. Then, use the "indexOf()" method to find the start and end of each bracket.  Here's more info on "indexOf()"  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp
3. Once you have the start and end of each bracket, use the substring method to extract the contents of the brackets.  More info on the substring method here:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

The end result would look something like this:

```
        var myStrings = document.getElementsByClassName("classNameHere");
        for(var i = 0; i < myStrings.length; i++){
            var start = myStrings[i].indexOf("[");
            var end = myStrings[i].indexOf("]");
            var extractedString = myStrings[i].substring(start, end);
            // Do your Ajax call here with the "extractedString" variable
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
var myString = "TRIAL [Sachet]";

var myRegexp = /\[(.*)\]+/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```

That regex will get you anything inside the `[]`.

One more thing for you to not is `!@#$%^&*()'RWEW<>?P{}:" [Sachet]` invalid string and you will need to escape the quotes.

`!@#$%^&*()'RWEW<>?P{}:\" [Sachet]`

Note the `\` before `"`